# Extranet / Intranet-portal

Tags: site, extranet, intranet, collection

First of all: I'm a Dutch man, so sorry for my bad English! I'm a newbie on sharepoint, I've read much about it and watch a lot of Youtube-video's, but I didn't find the answer for my question(s). Maybe you can help me!

I've Sharepoint Server 2013 on a local server (Windows Server 2012), it's a completenew installation.

For your information: I've an accounting office with 80/100 customers, and 5 employees.

I want to have an intranet where every employee can access every client-site. This intranet needs to be accessible for the customers (extranet), of course only the part witch contains the information about himself.

To ensure the safety of the data / backing up data/ moving data, I read, I need to create for every customer a single site collection (and every site collection his own database), witch contains for Example a teamsite.

I'm already so far, I can reach a webapplication from the outside of the office and log in to one site collection.

I've got 3 big questions:

**QUESTION 1:**
How can I make one login-page for every cliënt and employee (just like f.e. www.ebay.com) so that the cliënts will be redirected to their sitecollection and employee's to the "main"-collection where from every site collection can be reached?

**QUESTION 2A:**
So I create a Webcollection, named NETSHARE. I've got some cliënt information stored in an Excel-sheet: Cliëntnumber, Name of the cliënt, Address of the cliënt, logon-information [username/password] and so on.

I want to create automaticly multiple site collections: Cliënt01, Cliënt02, Cliënt03 and so on. The basic information of the cliënt needs to be stored in the Titlepage of the teamsite in every site collection.

What's the code to create this?

**QUESTION 2B:**
Is it possible to create automaticly logon-information (which is stored in the same Excel-sheet from Question 1?

If somebody could help me and give me the answers, it would be great! If somebody can give me the links to the articles to solve the questions, it would be too great!

Thank you veru much for your efforts till now!!!

Chris

Comment: Well Chris, So far I can say for Question 2A, You can create Site collection programatically by Powershell [Link here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/cc263094(v=office.15).aspx). And yes Powershell can read the CSV file so you can iterate through  CSV data and create all the site collection programatically! I guess this is the best approach!

Answer (score 0):

I'm also very new to SharePoint and had to do roughly the same as you have to do. To implement this, I used custom membership and role provider along with a custom log on page. Here's the two links I worked from:

1. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg317440(v=office.14).aspx (explains the concept in detail)
2. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tc47t75(v=vs.100).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1 (example)

You might not want to go this route at all, but it worked for me.